# Wicket form component that remembers previous state

Tags: wicket

I have a DropDownChoice with OnChangeAjaxBehavior. In the OnChangeAjaxBehavior, I have a conditional behavior - if the user selected the same value as the last time, the behavior should not do anything. How can I elegantly save the previous value? I tried

```
@Override
protected void onModelChanging() {
    this.previousValue = carDataModel.getObject().getModel();
    log.debug("Saving previous value from model: {}", previousValue);
}
```

But the method `onModelChanging()` method is not called **if the selected value is the same as the previous value** so the preivous value is not always updated properly.

Is there another method that gets called in the Wicket component lifecycle before the model gets updated I could use?

Comment: What I do is to store previousValue during the page initial construction & use that to populate the model for the dropdown, then use AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior to update the previousValue after the comparison has been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override #getUpdateModel() to return false, so in your #onUpdate() the component still has its original model object and you can access FormComponent#getConvertedInput() before calling component#updateModel() by yourself.